# error in spring hibernate integration

Tags: java, swing, hibernate, sockets

everytime when i am running my spring with hibernate socket program it saves for the first time but i am sending infinitely from the client side but in server end only first time it is saving..What type of problem i am facing?? how to resolve

```
package utilclass;


import org.hibernate.*;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;

public class HibernateUtemplate {


private static   HibernateTemplate template;
 public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template){
     HibernateUtemplate.template=template;
 }
 public static  SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
     return template.getSessionFactory();
 }
 public static Session getSession(){

    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

     return getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
 }

 public static   void commitTransaction() {
        getSession().getTransaction().commit();
    }
    public  static void rollbackTransaction() {
        getSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    public static  void closeSession() {
    getSession().close();
    }

}
```

this is my generic file

```
package daoimplclasses;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;


import utilclass.HibernateUtemplate;

import daointerfaces.GenericDao;

public abstract class GenericDaoimpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, ID> {
    //HibernateTemplate template;
     protected Session getSession() {
            return HibernateUtemplate.getSession();
        }
     public void save(T entity) {   
        //template.saveOrUpdate(entity);
         HibernateUtemplate.getSession().saveOrUpdate(entity);
        // HibernateUtemplate.beginTransaction().saveOrUpdate(entity);
                    }
     public void merge(T entity) {
        // template.merge(entity);
         HibernateUtemplate.getSession().merge(entity);
        // HibernateUtemplate.beginTransaction().merge(entity);
                    }
     public void update(T entity) {
        // template.update(entity);
         HibernateUtemplate.getSession().update(entity);
        // HibernateUtemplate.beginTransaction().update(entity);

        }
     public void delete(T entity) {
        // template.delete(entity);
         HibernateUtemplate.getSession().delete(entity);
         //HibernateUtemplate.beginTransaction().delete(entity);

        }
     public List<T> findMany(Query query) {

            List<T> t;
            t = (List<T>) query.list();
            return t;
        }

       public T findOne(Query query) {

            T t;
            t = (T) query.uniqueResult();

            return t;
        }

       public T findByID(Class claz,String siteid){

            T t=null;
            //t=(T)template.get(claz, siteid);
            t=(T) HibernateUtemplate.getSession().get(claz, siteid);

        //t=(T) HibernateUtemplate.beginTransaction().get(claz, siteid);  
            return t;
        }
       public List<T> findAll(Class clazz) {

            List<T> T = null;

            Query query= HibernateUtemplate.getSession().createQuery("from "+clazz.getName());

           // Query query= HibernateUtemplate.beginTransaction().createQuery("from "+clazz.getName());

            T = query.list();

            return T;
        }

}
```

Comment: Need to look at relevant code.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: dr is no error but the data which i am sending from client side continuously should be checked and saved in database in server side continuously but only for once it is dumping.. but i need continuously..

Comment: if i use only hibernate den d data is dumping continuosly but if i am using spring + hibernate den it is dumping for once